# Android window - view animation

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

Hello I'm new to titanium studio I'm reading the docs 2 days now and trying to make a simple slide animation or even any animation of any kind except opening a modal window. but I can't make it work.Here is what I was trying now but fails:

```
var slide_it_left = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    slide_it_left.left = 500; 
    slide_it_left.duration = 500;

var mainWinOpts = {
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    fullscreen:true,
    navBarHidden: true
}

var animWinOpts = {
    navBarHidden: true,
    backgroundColor:'#000',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
    height: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
    fullscreen:false,
    animated:true       
}

var mainWin = Ti.UI.createWindow(mainWinOpts);
var animWin = Ti.UI.createWindow(animWinOpts); 

var labelOpts = {
    text: 'click me!',
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    font: {
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        fontSize: 24
    },
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: '#2e2e2e',
    borderColor: '#2e2e2e',
    backgroundColor: '#dedede',
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
    height: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
    opacity: 1.00,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
};

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel(labelOpts);

label.addEventListener('click',function(){
    animWin.open(slide_it_left);
})

mainWin.add(label);
mainWin.open();
```

This among other snippets I tried from their docs - forums isn't working.
Could someone please provide me some working samples or references for android window or view animation. Or point out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing your code to the following:

```
label.addEventListener('click',function(){
    animWin.open();
    animWin.animate(slide_it_left);
});
```

You cannot use the animation object as a parameter for open().
Have a look at the valid params [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/openWindowParams).

Moreover, the docs give an example for sliding in a window on Android, which is very likely what you are trying to achieve:

```
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({fullscreen:false});
win2.open({
    activityEnterAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
    activityExitAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.slide_out_right
});
```

You can find the animations for the Android platform [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html).

Comment: You saved me mate thank you I didn't know it was that simple and I didn't came across your second link when I was searching. Thank you very much!