# Titanium window open animation left to right showing black screen

Tags: android, animation, titanium

Titanium SDK: 3.1.2 Platform: Android Titanium Studio: 3.1.3.
Hi all
I am new for Titanium and trying to add some animation to my window. When the window opens, it should open from left to right.
I have achieved this with following code.
But there is a problem, before showing animated  window, a black screen appears.
So my questions are:-
1) What should i do to remove the black screen..?
2) What should i do to close the same window with animation right to left when clicking android back arrow button..?

```
//Application Window Component Constructor

var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#123',
    navBarHidden:false,
    exitOnClose:true
});

var devWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({title:'Click',width:100,height:50});
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var detailContainerWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title: 'View Details',
        navBarHidden: false,
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });

    detailContainerWindow.addEventListener('open', function(){
        var anim1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            left: "-" + devWidth,
            duration: 1000
        });
        detailContainerWindow.animate(anim1);
    });

    detailContainerWindow.open();
});

self.add(button);
```

Comment: You should find the answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978233/android-window-view-animation/18978399#18978399).

Answer (score 1):

do not execute animation on open event just execute after .open method.

```
var anim1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            left: "-" + devWidth,
            duration: 1000
        });
        detailContainerWindow.animate(anim1);

 var button = Ti.UI.createButton({title:'Click',width:100,height:50});

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var detailContainerWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title: 'View Details',
        navBarHidden: false,
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });

    detailContainerWindow.addEventListener('open', function(){

    });

    detailContainerWindow.open();
    detailContainerWindow.animate(anim1);

});
```

and to close that windoiw with animation you use androidback event of winnow.

```
   var anim2 = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
                left: devWidth,
                duration: 1000
            });

detailContainerWindow.addEventListener('androidback', function(){
              detailContainerWindow.animate(anim2);
        });
```

Comment: thats because of duration time 1000 so it will 1 min to animate window from left to right.

Comment: Hallo @MitulBhalia duration : 1000  means 1 seconds not 1 minute.